# Multiple functions in one setInterval()?

Tags: jquery

I have two setInterval each running a function every 20s. Is there a way to put both functions under the same setInterval call?

```
setInterval(function(){
 //function a
}, 20000);

setInterval(function(){
 //function b
}, 20000);
```

To something like:

```
setInterval( (functionA, functionB) , 20000);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just call both the functions within another callback function like

```
setInterval(function () {
    functionA();
    functionB();
}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you define a third function that calls the two functions, you can just call that third function as follows:

```
function functionC() {
   functionA();
   functionB();
}

setInterval( functionC, 20000 );
```